# "As opposed to" and "contrary to" in the beginning of sentences

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I open a sentence with "**As opposed to**" and "**contrary to**"? 
I always heard them in the middle of sentence but not in the beginning of it,  and that's why I'm not sure about it.

Examples:

> **As opposed to** what people think, there are not only three states of matter: solid, liquid and gas.  But there are four,  plasma is additional state of matter.
>
> **Contrary to** what people think, there are not only three states of matter: solid, liquid and gas,  but there are four,  since plasma is additional state of matter.

Comment: Did you mean to write *as* before *contrary to*?

Comment: Yes,  but I understood from the answers that it is incorrect,  so in order to focus on my main question,  I edited it.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the second sentence. You can start it with "Contrary to ..." sure, but the sentence construction looks a bit off to me.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't quite the same.

"As opposed to" usually suggests something is an *alternative*, for example:

> The box is made of plastic, as opposed to wood.

This suggests that *some* boxes are made of wood, but this box is made of plastic instead. It doesn't in any way *deny* that other boxes are made of wood.

---

"Contrary to" usually suggests an *opposite*, but also that whatever it is being *compared* to may be false, for example:

> Contrary to opinion, our boxes are made from plastic, not wood.

This means that the boxes are made from plastic, not wood - but also refutes any idea that they were made of wood.

---

In answer to your question then - you can open a sentence with "contrary to[x]", because you will immediately go on to state both the incorrect notion and the correct one.

It is not common to open a sentence with "as opposed to". "As" is here being used as an adverb, and while you *can* open a sentence with an adverb, it is much more common to begin a sentence with the *conjunction* "as", for example "As it is raining today, we will stay inside". Opening a sentence with "as opposed to" feels wrong to me as an English speaker because of that ambiguity. It isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you,  but the question wasn't about the meaning of them. Kindly, read it again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies partly with the construction of your sentences.

**As opposed to** doesn't fit well in this context; **a fourth state of matter** is not opposed to what people may think. That's to say it is not the opposite. To be wrong about something is not necessarily opposed to what is correct. If I say there are three dogs next door when there are four, pointing out the fourth does not oppose my statement. It merely corrects it.

On the other hand **contrary to** is fine. It fits the context.

However, you could improve the second sentence by changing it to read:

> Contrary to what people think, there are not only three states of matter: solid, liquid and gas, but four; plasma is an additional state of matter.